# LinqJs Perform "WHERE IN (Value1,Value2)" Queries

Tags: angularjs, linq, contain

I am using [**linq js**](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) to perform `WHERE IN (Value1,Value2)` but getting an error `x.id.Contains is not a function`

```
$http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
    var dta = response.data;

    $scope.hdr = Enumerable.From(dta)
        .Where(function (x) { return x.id.Contains([1,3]) })
        .Select(function(x) {
            return x
        })
        .ToArray();


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are enumerating over the list, and using Contains on a specific ID instead of doing that on a list, You need to modify the code accordingly